# Run XSS payload after syntax error in script tag?

Tags: xss, javascript

Recently, during a security audit, I found a page in which some URL parameter is reflected inside a `<script>` tag. It could be an easy XSS, but a line before the reflection there is a syntax error (e.g., string without ending quotes).

Is it possible to make JavaScript code run in spite of a syntax error one or more lines above it?

Answer (score 2):

If there is a syntax error inside a script tag, no code in the block will be executed, neither above or below it. So to get some code running, you have two options:

- Fix the syntax error using the code you are injecting. Depedning on what kind of error it is, this may or may not be possible. E.g. closing a quote two lines up sounds impossible, but balancing brackets should be doable.
- End the script tag with the syntax error, and start a new clean one. If there is no filter at all you can inject e.g. `<script>alert("XSS");</script><script>`-